# How to implement public private key in my own api / eat own dog food

Tags: python, api, oauth

I've read the entire OAuth documentation and specification and a good amount of other documentation and I understand in theory how it is supposed to work. I have a hard time finding any documentation on actual authentication for one's own API implemented in any language.

I understand that I need to provide a public and private key and I assume I get the private key from Flask-Login and store it in the database but I don't know how to generate a public key, or match the public and private for authentication. Basically the whole process of secure API Authentication.

I have a main website, a mobile webapp, and a mobile app I am developing and I'd like to make an API for them all so I can "eat my own dog food." Which I read in from a Soundcloud article. The only issue I see is providing authentication since I normally do that through Flask-Login and sessions.

I am using Python with Flask, Flask-Restful and Flask-Login and Flask MongoEngine. I see that Flask-Login provides a token. 
I've setup www.myapp.com api.myapp.com and m.myapp.com. I'll be using HTTPS when the time comes.

I'd like to implement my own public private key authentication.

Comment: Flask has ready OAuth package http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/

Comment: Do you want to implement an OAuth authentication for your webservice or your own implementation of public/private key authentication framework?

Comment: @lcfseth I'd like to roll my own.